# Does passing an IRS audit with flying colors affect in any way the probability of an audit in a later year?

Tags: united-states, income-tax

I am asking this out of curiosity; we will not change our good behavior on tax reporting based on this answer!

Several years ago, we had a thorough audit on our federal income tax return (US).  The result -- the IRS agreed with everything we did and even concluded that our tax was 67 cents **less** than we had calculated -- round-off difference.

Does passing an audit reduce the likelihood of being audited in subsequent years; does it have **any effect at all** on the likelihood of being audited again?

**Addendum in response to a comment.**  In our case, our charitable contributions were very large for our income, and it was clear that the IRS saw this as anomalous and needing verification.

Comment: To be clear, you mean compared to not having been audited at all, right? I am pretty sure passing the audit makes you less likely to be audited again *than if you failed the audit*.

Comment: @nanoman -- yes compared to not having been audited.

Comment: I don't know the audit algorithm so I can't say for sure, but logically the answer *should* be no, because if the answer was yes, then people who recently passed an audit would have more incentive to cheat in subsequent years, which would be counter-productive to the algorithm.

Comment: @TTT: I contend that the logical answer would be *yes* in many cases.  If the previous audit were triggered (i.e. likelihood increased) by a "red flag", and the taxpayer turned out to have a fully legitimate reason for that unusual pattern, then logically that flag should be ignored for that taxpayer going forward, and they should return to the base probability of being audited.

Comment: @BenVoigt excellent point. I agree in that case, for a specific flag. I suppose my comment should be focused more on random audits.

Comment: Besides that, lowering the probability (even below the base rate) would help avoid the appearance that particular individuals are being harassed for political reasons, and not just randomly selected.  You might not do this after the first audit, though.  But since [the audit rate is 200:1](https://www.irs.gov/statistics/enforcement-examinations), the US population is large enough you'd expect pure randomness to produce strings of 3 and 4 consecutive audits, and it's probably a bad idea to let that happen, both politically and in terms of the work dropped on those people.

Comment: @Ben Voigt  "....in terms of the work dropped on those people."  Oh Yes!  Even with well organized perfect records, an audit is a time-consuming PIA and boring, boring, boring.  I think your comments add up to a worthwhile answer.

Comment: @ab2: Unfortunately my analysis of what logic would dictate doesn't even begin to answer the question of what the IRS actually does.